# jquery search for a table cell -> update neighboring cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How do I go about finding a table cell with value (text) of "foo" and setting the next cell in that row to "bar"?

The cell to be set may already contain some text that needs to be overwritten.

Comment: Did you something? Please show some code

Answer (score 1):

Try this but i haven`t tested it.

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === 'foo'
}).next('td').text('bar')
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BeVdCnHh1h9sy1wzVB4u?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowList = document.getElementById('tableID').children;
for (var i=0, len = rowList.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var row = rowList[i];
    var cellList = row.children;
    for (var j=0, size = cellList.length; j < size; ++j) {
        var cell = cellList[j];
        //need additional check to avoid out of bounds issues
        if (cell.innerHTML == 'foo' && cellList[j + 1]) {
            cellList[j + 1].innerHTML = 'bar';
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

sorry missed the jQuery tag. The answer above is fine but I believe the calls to `.text()` should be `.html()`